# How to subtract std::unordered_map vector elements from one to other and update it in C++?

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I have two `std::unordered_map`s in C++ where the key is an Index (unsigned integer) and the value is a vector of real numbers. The maps are defined as the following:

```
std::unordered_map<Index, std::vector<Real>> outgoing_msgs;

std::unordered_map<Index, std::vector<Real>> outgoing_msgs_prev;
```

These 2 unordered_maps have the same structures, and size properties, and also they have the same key values, same vector size but the difference resides in the vector element values.

I want to obtain the subtraction of the vector values of `outgoing_msgs` (the first unordered_map) from the values of the vector of `outgoing_msgs_prev` (which is the second unordered_map) based on the index, which means that the subtraction of the vector will happen for the vectors that have same keys (Indexes) in both unordered maps.

Is it possible?

What is the fastest way to do it?

Comment: "_Is it possible?_" Yes. What have you tried, to accomplish this?

Comment: Which map do you want to modify? Or do you literally want the differences only?

Comment: My first thought was [std::set_difference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference)...

Comment: There is nothing that will easily help you . You will have to loop through one of the maps and look-up in the other one. Ideally loop through whichever would be the smaller one.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like

```cpp
for(auto &[key, val]: outgoing_msgs)
{
   auto &prev{outgoing_msgs_prev[key]};
   for(std::size_t i{}; i < val.size(); ++i) val[i] -= prev[i];
}
```

?